# VBA - How do I call a section of code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am still very new to the world of VBA in Excel so this might be a very obvious question.

I have 2 sections of code that I use often throughout the long script I have written. What I want to do is ideally give these 2 sections of code a name and then 'Call' them when needed instead of writing them out each time (about 30 lines of code each).

Is this possible and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: Lines of code are grouped together in named `Sub` procedures or `Functions`. 
To execute them you simply address (call) the name. See *Creating and Calling Procedures* @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa188202(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: see also this http://www.anthony-vba.kefra.com/vba/vbabasic1.htm#Calling_Sub_Procedures_and_Function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Example, if you have 2 variables that you keep adding if the conditions are met;

```
Sub Main()

    Dim x As Double
    Dim y As Double
    Dim sum As Double

    x = 2
    y = 3
    If x > y And x > 0 And y > 0 Then
        sum = x + y
    End If

    x = 7
    y = 8
    If x > y And x > 0 And y > 0 Then
        sum = x + y
    End If

End Sub
```

Following the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) you may want to create a function. A function will take 2 parameters and return the sum if condition is met, so you can use it over and over without repeating the `if statement` all over the place.

For example

```
Function AddIfConditionMet(x As Double, y As Double)
    If x > y And x > 0 And y > 0 Then
        AddIfConditionMet = x + y
    Else
        AddIfConditionMet = -1
    End If
End Function
```

Each time this function is called it checks the conditions - if they are met then it adds `x` and `y` if not then it returns `-1`

Sample code

```
Sub Main()

    Dim x As Double
    Dim y As Double
    Dim sum As Double

    x = 2
    y = 3
    sum = AddIfConditionMet(x, y) ' returns -1
    Debug.Print sum

    x = 10
    y = 5
    sum = AddIfConditionMet(x, y) ' returns 15
    Debug.Print sum

End Sub

Function AddIfConditionMet(x As Double, y As Double)
    If x > y And x > 0 And y > 0 Then
        AddIfConditionMet = x + y
    Else
        AddIfConditionMet = -1
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: That's a brilliant answer and very detailed. However, I'm not sure if it is too in depth for what I need. You example appears to require conditions. I want to just call a 'function' when asked for it. This may be multiple times in the same script but after doing different things.....If that makes sense.

Comment: You can convert your functions to procedures. It's quite easy, but bear in mind that procedures do not return values. See Alex's comment under your question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sub main
 dim a as long
 call First_Macro ( arg1, Arg2 , Arg3)      'same as : First_macro arg1, Arg2, Arg3
 a= Some_Function_Name ( Arg1, Arg2, Arg3)
End sub



Sub First_macro (Byval arg 1 as string, byval arg2 as long, byref arg3 as range)
 'do something
end sub


Function Some_Function_Name ( Arg1, Arg2, Arg3) as long 'returns a Long type value
 'Do something
 if sometthing happens then
     Some_Function_Name=x
 else
     Some_Function_Name=x+1 'for example
 end if
end function
```

Comment: your comment is misleading. see calling subs/functions with parameters with and without brackets. They are different ways of passing objects to functions ( byRef and ByVal )